# If string contains a letter, throw error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, string

passing in a list of strings :

```
List<string> quantity
```

if string contains all numbers, code is fine. However if user enters a 'letter' in the quantity section and submits the code breaks.

Need to do a check in the quantity list that it does not contain letters, if so return VIEW with error message:

```
foreach (string q in quantity)
{
    if (q //if q == letter?)
    {
        _notifier.Information(T("A letter has been entered for quantity. Please enter a number"));

        return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }
}
```

How can I say is q is a letter?

thanks for any replies

Comment: Would it be correct to say 1.000000000E100 is valid or invalid? Whilst a valid number it also contains a letter.

Comment: Why not use a `List<int>`?

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`Char.IsLetter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yyxz6h5w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), here's a short LINQ version which checks if any string contains letters:

```
bool anyWrong = quantity.Any(s => s.Any(Char.IsLetter));
```

or the opposite way, check if all are valid using [`Char.IsDigit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0ddtxh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
bool allCorrect = quantity.All(s => s.All(Char.IsDigit));
```

Another option is to check if all strings can be parsed to `int` or `long`, e.g.:

```
long l;
bool allCorrect = quantity.All(s => long.TryParse(s, out l));
```

If you also want to allow exponential notation, you can use `decimal.TryParse` with `NumberStyles.Float`:

```
List<string> quantity = new List<string> { "1000000000E-100" };
decimal d;
bool allCorrect = quantity
   .All(s => decimal.TryParse(s, NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out d));
```

Comment: does this include control characters as well?

Comment: @thumbmunkeys: have a look at the remarks section of both msdn pages linked above to see what characters are included.

Comment: @PaulZahra: no, control-characters or white-spaces are not letters or digits. No, `1.000000000E100` would return `false` if you check `s.All(Char.IsDigit)`. But that depends on OP's requirement if such a string should be a valid number or not. You can use `long.TryParse` instead as mentioned.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Indeed, that's why I deleted the point I made from your post and posted it against the OP.

Comment: @PaulZahra: i've already edited my answer to provide a way to allow even  xponential notation.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Good one, my point is nevertheless valid for the other posters and not least to make the question more definitive; shame the OP has gone AFK :D

Comment: Just done a check to ensure all char are digits, if not throw error: bool allCorrect = quantity.All(s => s.All(Char.IsDigit));
thanks guys for help

Answer (score 4):

You can use a LINQ extension method for that:

```
if (!q.All(Char.IsDigit)) {
  // not only digits
}
```

Comment: q is list of strings not a string ;)

Comment: @ArsenMkrt: No, it's not. The variable `quantity` holds the list of strings. The variable `q` is used in the loop to reference each string in the list.

Comment: @ArsenMkrt It becomes a collection of char when you iterate over it with Linq. That code works perfectly.

Comment: if you mean q as a string from loop, than I would rather check q.Any(Char.IsLetter), it would be faster, if for example first symbol is letter

Comment: @ArsenMkrt No, `All` would fail *just as fast* in that case. And `IsLetter` is *not* the opposite of `IsDigit`.

Comment: @ArsenMkrt: That would only check for letters, but a string like `"/&¤%/&%"` does't contain letters but is still not possible to parse as a number. Besides, if any of the strings fail the performance is not critical as that would go to a redirect, and in the normal case where all strings pass you have to go through all characters in all strings, so there is no early exit.

Comment: ok, right, it depends what is inside the string. I agree overall performance is the same

Answer (score 3):

Since you have tagged this as MVC.. you should be using Data Annotations to validate your properties. E.g.:

```
public class YourModel {
    public IList<QuantityModel> Quantities { get; set; }
}

public class QuantityModel {
    [RegularExpression(@"\d+")] // <--- this
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}
```

This saves you from manually validating your properties... as you are currently attempting to do.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you accept *positive integer numbers* only, you should check if *each string* within list is not empty or null and contains *anything but digits* (not only *letters* that are 'A'..'Z', 'a'..'z' but, say '+', '{', *command characters* etc). You can do it by LINQ:

```
  // All strings within quantity contains digits only
  if (!quantity.All(c => (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(c)) && c.All(Char.IsDigit(c)))) {
    _notifier.Information(T("A letter has been entered for quantity. Please enter a number"));

    return Redirect(returnUrl);
  }
```